# Jboss 4.2 + socket

Tags: sockets, jboss

Trying an R&D, we need to create a socket client in web application (Jboss 4.2) am completely blank. Need you help in the following queries

A) To create socket client shall we use Jboss JMS (queue/PTP) functionality,

1) Is it good concept?

2) What are the steps for configuring the Queue details & where to set
    the connection details (host address, timeout is there any pooling
    size option).

3) Based on the above how do we handle the response from Socket server
    (Asynchronus & what would be the clustering effect).

B) Or is there any other way to configure socket using mbean, if so where can I refer the same for Jboss 4.2.

Tried my best to explain what is there in my mind.

Comment: Tried R&D  JMS queue to java socket server was getting Exception EOF. clueless on how to create the layer

Comment: A lot of confusion can we access using the Jboss + JMS , Or simply create a POJO for Soket